# Move json column in csv to another file with python

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I have a **test.dat** file that contains this 5 column:

- ['user_id', 'item_id', 'rating', 'scraping_time',
  'tweet_in_json_format']

I want to **Move** this three columns to **test2.csv** :

- ['user_id','scraping_time', 'tweet_in_json_format']

Here is an example of one row of test.dat:

```
user_id,item_id,rating,scraping_time,tweet_in_json_format
819099800,0993846,10,1391278544,{"contributors": null, "truncated": false, "text": "", "in_reply_to_status_id": null, "id": 426902385735520256, "favorite_count": 0, "source": "<a href=\"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/imdb-movies-tv/id342792525?mt=8&uo=4\" rel=\"nofollow\">IMDb Movies & TV on iOS</a>", "retweeted": false, "coordinates": null, "entities": {"symbols": [], "user_mentions": [], "hashtags": [{"indices": [61, 66], "text": "IMDb"}], "urls": [{"url": "http://tweeter.com/xQuwO8KJP1", "indices": [38, 60], "expanded_url": "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0993846", "display_url": "imdb.com/title/tt0993846"}]}, "in_reply_to_screen_name": null, "id_str": "426902385735520256", "retweet_count": 0, "in_reply_to_user_id": null, "favorited": false, "user": {"follow_request_sent": false, "profile_use_background_image": true, "id": 819099800, "verified": false, "profile_text_color": "333333", "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/420936276607791104/KVrTuNU9_normal.jpeg", "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6", "is_translator": false, "geo_enabled": false, "entities": {"description": {"urls": []}}, "followers_count": 116, "protected": false, "location": "in my dreams ", "default_profile_image": false, "id_str": "819099800", "lang": "ar", "utc_offset": -36000, "statuses_count": 1169, "description": "\u0646\u0628\u0649 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u062c\u0631 .", "friends_count": 86, "profile_link_color": "0084B4", "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/420936276607791104/KVrTuNU9_normal.jpeg", "notifications": false, "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/812779345/23ae1c7da01b05a6d5d9b0be28fe14c9.jpeg", "profile_background_color": "C0DEED", "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/819099800/1390618207", "profile_background_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/812779345/23ae1c7da01b05a6d5d9b0be28fe14c9.jpeg", "name": "vivo per lei ", "is_translation_enabled": false, "profile_background_tile": false, "favourites_count": 155, "screen_name": "Orkida__", "url": null, "created_at": "Wed Sep 12 08:08:06 +0000 2012", "contributors_enabled": false, "time_zone": "Hawaii", "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED", "default_profile": false, "following": false, "listed_count": 0}, "geo": null, "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null, "possibly_sensitive": false, "lang": "en", "created_at": "Sat Jan 25 02:20:34 +0000 2014", "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null, "place": null}
```

The problem is that the'tweet_in_json_format' is **json** and **Pandas** can't consider that into a column....

How can i do this ?

Comment: converting json to string?

Comment: JSON is a string. What's the problem?

Comment: @faboolous no, this json column should read as a part of dataframe in pandas. for example df[4] represent as "tweet_in_json_format" column

Comment: @Hossein Do you want to convert it into a python dict or leave it as a string? Because I guarantee it'll be a string when it is read in.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ respectfully disagree, it's a string when enclosed in quotation marks, which would be `'{"contributors"...null, "place": null}'`. remember it's a csv file

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ it doesn't matter, i just want to move 3 column to another csv file and my problem with the json formatted column.....

Comment: @Hossein you need to be clearer of what you want to do and what you are already doing. what is the separator of the csv file? It it's `,` as in *comma* separated values, then your csv file is already invalid, as your tweet_in_json_format also contains commas

Comment: @faboolous exactly, how can i change my separator in all rows ?

Comment: Be more specific about the types of data involved here, and show what you've already tried, along with any errors or issues you encountered.

Comment: you should use another separator for the other columns, e.g `819099800|0993846|10|1391278544|,{"contributors": null, "truncated"`.....Then when you read the csv you need to indicate `|` to be your separator - or whatever you choose it to be, just try to avoid something which can be inside the json string....

Comment: @faboolous tnx i will try this and say the results.

Comment: In order words, your json contains undelimited commas, so how is that csv parser working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that your input isn't actually CSV - if it were, the JSON data in the last column would have to be quoted so that its internal commas are not interpreted as CSV delimiters.

If you simply want to perform the transformation you describe, and you can be confident of the input format remaining the same (i.e. user ID, item ID, rating, scraping time and JSON data in that order, separated with commas), then this can be achieved relatively simply without needing Pandas (which is really overkill for the job):

```
with open('test.dat') as f_in, open('test2.csv', 'w') as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        parts = line.split(',', 4)
        f_out.write('{},{},{}\n'.format(parts[0], parts[3], parts[4]))
```

In short, this opens the input and output files, then for each line in the input file it splits it *at most* four times on the commas, which separates the line into its various fields without mangling the JSON. It then writes the first, fourth and fifth fields (corresponding to user ID, scraping time and JSON data) to the output file, separated with commas.

Please note that this is a slightly brittle solution, as it will break if the column order changes.